# extend mysql date

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to code so that when a certain date is reached, then that is displayed in the report. What I would like to do is to find a way so that when a date is reached, ie, today, then keep the entry in the report until a user deletes it. So instead of it just showing today and not beyond, I need to find a way to show when a date is reached, it is displayed until deleted.

```
mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn); 
$query = "SELECT * FROM boxes WHERE customer = '$_SESSION[kt_idcode_usr]' AND destroy_date = DATE(NOW()) AND status = 1"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: @Webnet That does not apply to the [**string parsing rules**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM boxes WHERE customer = '$_SESSION[kt_idcode_usr]' AND 
destroy_date <= DATE(NOW()) AND status = 1";
```

this will return, when a date is reached, it is displayed until deleted.

if row is deleted no record would be there.